# On which object/class does DelegateClass and similar methods live?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Sorry for the poor title, but I'm a bit lost.

I'm trying to figure out on which object/class live methods such as DelegateClass and what is the term for these types of methods. I'm reading *Metaprogramming Ruby* and, in the book, these methods are generically called Mimic Methods, but searching the internet for this gives all kinds of results, so I'm wondering if there's a better name for them.

I've checked the source code of [DelegateClass](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_2_290/lib/delegate.rb) and I assumed that it was added to Object, but it's not there. I can see the the classes Delegator and SimpleDelegator, which are in the same rb file, are *added* as constants (although I'm not sure how they are added).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer. It's a private method in Object

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :033 > Object.private_instance_methods(false).grep /Dele/
 => [:DelegateClass]
```

**edit**

I found out that what I needed to understand is *What is the current class?* in a given context.

Comment: This is the correct answer (the 'selected' answer is wrong), but use `method(:DelegateClass).owner` to verify instead of grep ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the file.

```
def DelegateClass(superclass)
  klass = Class.new(Delegator)
  ...
```

and use

```
method(:DelegateClass).owner
```

to find the class where it sits. As mentioned in the comments private instance methods on Module contain anything defined on Object.

So no, `DelegateClass()` is not a special method in any way except for being called in uppercase (which makes it look like a constant). It just returns an anonymous class created on-the-spot that can be inherited from.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julik! The very important bit that I didn't know, was that methods defined in a script are added to Module!! And by the way, I defined a method in `irb` and it was added to Module (no idea if it works on pry).

Comment: @Julik: This is incorrect, the method is defined as a private instance method on `Object` no matter whether it's defined in irb or pry or running in a ruby script, use the `Method#owner` to uncover this: `method(:DelegateClass).owner => Object`. The reason your `Module.private_instance_method` returned the result you got is because `Module` is a subclass of Object. Nonetheless, `DelegateClass` is a private instance method on `Object`.